# Getting invalid style for any type of decimal separator in input type=“number”

Tags: css, html, validation

```
<input type="number" name="quantity2" value="1.1" >
```

I have a CSS which colors input with nonvalid data (number).

But it colors both inputs with decimal point or decimal comma

check here:

http://jsfiddle.net/pjvkh0zc/1/

try to type 1.1 or 1,1
- on my chrome they are both red

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add a `step` attribute

```css
  input:invalid {
    border: 2px solid red;
  }
```

```html
<input type="number" name="quantity1" pattern="[-+]?[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]+" step="any">

<input type="number" name="quantity1" pattern="[-+]?[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]+" step="0.1">
```

> Numeric input fields can take additional attributes “min” and “step”, which constrain the range of values allowed in your input. The “min” attribute is fairly obvious: it’s the minimum value your number can be. The “step” attribute is less intuitive: by playing with different values, you would most likely work out that it controls the increase/decrease when clicking the up/down buttons on the field. If you input the number 1 and click the up arrow, it will increase to 2. This is because the default step is 1. So far, so obvious. However, the step attribute also determines which values are valid, so a step of 1 means you can enter 1, 2, 3 etc. and a step of 2 means you can enter 2, 4, 6 etc, and when you click the up/down buttons the number will increase/decrease by 2 each time, but entering 3 or 5 in the box will cause a validation error. You can also use a decimal value: for example, a step of 0.3 will allow values such as 0.3, 0.6, 0.9 etc, but not 1 or 2.
>
> But what if you want all the numbers to be valid, integers and decimals alike? In this case, set step to “any”:

```
<input type="number" step="any" />
```

> Now you don’t get a validation error. Yay! Also note that if you only want to accept positive numbers, you’ll want to add min=”0″.

Found in this [**Article**](http://blog.isotoma.com/2012/03/html5-input-typenumber-and-decimalsfloats-in-chrome/)

Answer (score 1):

`input type="number"` takes a further attribute, `step`, which controls what values are valid, and what the +/- buttons beside the input field do. It defaults to 1. Changing it to 0.1, for example, will allow numbers like 0.1, 0.2, etc.